# Unknown error when comparing element in string to a character

Tags: c++, pointers

```
1.     int wordCount;
2.     for (int x = 0; x < sen.length(); x++)
3.     {
4.          if (sen.at(x) == " ") {wordCount++;}
5      }
```

I am trying increase the wordCount each time an element in the string is empty. But whenever I run the code it generates an error at line 4 which says `ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and an integer`. 
Can someone tell me how to fix this and why I keep on getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

`" "` is not a character, is a string literal consisting of two caracters: the space and the null terminator. The space character would be `' '`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (sen.at(x) == " ") {wordCount++;}
```

`" "` is a string literal , you need to use single quotes -

```
if (sen.at(x) ==' ') {wordCount++;}
```

Or you can use function [`isspace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/) .

Answer (score 0):

what's the type of sen? The types are probably incompatible

Answer (score 0):

`" "` is a string literal. You are comparing `const char*` with `char` which is illegal and not what you are trying to do. Replace `"` by `'`.